# Check whether the function is convex or concave or neither.

Tags: convex-analysis

So I have a given function $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:x_1,x_2>0\}$

$f(x)=12x_1^\frac{1}{3}x_2^\frac{1}{2}$

How do I check the convexity of the function ? I thought of proceeding via finding the eigenvalues of the hessian matrix, but it seems like a tedious job, and I am not even sure if that would lead to anything conclusive. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: perhaps show your working of computing the Hessian matrix?

Comment: *Hint:* Draw a picture of $f(1, x_2) = 12 \sqrt{x_2}$. Does that look convex?

Comment: @MartinR Yup, I plotted the graph, looks concave, is there any clean way to prove that tho ? Or hessian is the only way to go ?

Comment: Computing the Hessian should be not too bad if you extract common factors from the rows and columns of the determinant. I am not aware of a shorter method right now.